# open source code for extracting API call sequences and control flow graphs from assembly code

Tags: c++, api, assembly

Is there any open source code for extracting API call sequences and control flow graphs from assembly code?

I use a disassembler to come up with the assembly code of a PE file first. And now I need to extract the API call sequences and of course the cfg.

Comment: From a deleted answer: https://pypi.org/project/barf/0.3/#description Binary Analysis and Reverse engineering Framework might be useful here, specifically BARFcfg and BARFcg to extract a control-flow graph and call graph from a binary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to have a look at [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) in combination with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). There you are able to parse the call tree of the clang-generated bit code, which is an intermediate language and can be compiled to a target architecture afterwards. The [CallGraphSCCPass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#CallGraphSCCPass) should be helpful.

**Edit** As you are needing a disassembly first maybe [x86 Disassembler](http://blog.llvm.org/2010/01/x86-disassembler.html) with LLVM is more useful.

Comment: AFAIK, LLVM does not (yet?) have a frontend that parses assembly so it won't be of much help here.

Comment: Right, but there is the x86 Disassembler, maybe it helps, made an edit.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I don't how that disassembler can be used to generate LLVM IR, which is what is needed to use all the nice things like call graphs.

Comment: But as described on the linked blog page it seems that you can extract instructions by using the disassembler, or I've read something wrong, but I'm pretty sure that I didn't ;)

Comment: Yes but the OP already has the instructions:-) What you need is something that generates LLVM IR given these instructions.

Comment: Ok, now your concerns are clear to me ... no, my intention was that the OP uses `llvm-mc` (or similar) to regenerate the instructions, but I don't know whether it's possible for him, but I thought it's worth the suggestion ;)